# Can this sentence be ordered differently?

Tags: word-order

> John and Tom, working together effectively, were gathered in the basement.

I don't believe there's a problem with this.  But what if you change the order to:

> The ones gathered in the basement were John and Tom, working together effectively.

In this case, I am hoping to begin the sentence with "The ones..."

Comment: First of all, you're doing much more than changing the order; you're adding structure and pronouns. Second, the original sentence has already been done things to, with a participial clause stuffed inside the main clause.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did add a little.  But is that an acceptable sentence?  Or would you have to make that two sentences and add "And they were working together effectively."

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the second sentence? Proofreading (which this is, if you don't specify what you think is wrong) is off-topic for this site.

Comment: If you don't recognize what you did, how can you understand whether it's right or not?

Comment: Something seems odd to me about the second half.  I'm wondering if it would normally be divided into a second sentence, perhaps separated by a semicolon.  After making it a complete sentence, of course.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't really think ***two*** people are enough to ***gather***.

Comment: @Fumble - I had the same thought! Still, [Jesus](http://biblehub.com/matthew/18-20.htm) apparently thought two was enough to _gather_ – or at least the many of the translators did.

Comment: @J.R.: Firstly, Jesus didn't speak English. Secondly, it wouldn't surprise me if his "original" word/s for "two or three" were actually more akin to our "several". Which most people don't really think could include "two" (idiomatically people don't even say "two or three" very often unless there's a strong likelihood of it being more than two; if not, they just say "a couple").

Comment: @Fumble - ;^) Did I really need to include the winky emoticon? I thought my _translators_ remark would be enough of a hint.

Comment: @J.R.: As you know, I can be remarkably slow on the uptake! :-(

Comment: @FumbleFingers The ODE doesn't say it cannot be used for *two* people. It might be idiomatically wrong, but grammatically seems okay.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is fine. But, I would reorder it as:

> Working together effectively, John and Tom were gathered in the basement.

-or-

> John and Tom were gathered in the basement,  working together effectively.

Leading the sentence with "The ones" sounds rather awkward.

Comment: +1 these are other perfectly acceptable examples. Also I too find "The ones..." awkward.

Comment: That poses a problem because I want to try and start the sentence with "The ones"

Comment: Actually I guess miercoledi had a good suggestion too.  I could play around with that.

Comment: It was just John and Tom in the basement, working effectively together.

Comment: @Sai Miercoledi's suggestion is excellent. If you insist on leading with The ones, allow me to suggest:  The ones working together effectively in the basement were Tom and John.

Comment: 'The ones' is one of those classic "taught but never spoken" constructs - it sounds hilarious to a native speaker.

Comment: @OllieFord I don't know that I would characterize it as hilarious.  But, definitely odd to my ear as well.

Comment: @DavidM Poor use, I should be more careful on english.stack! I was dodging 'funny' being read as 'odd'. It's humorous.

Comment: @OllieFord I'll give you a pass!  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

*Gathered in the basement were John and Tom, working together effectively*

is good, I think. Several other arrangements exist, a few of which involve no addition or subtraction of words. As the writer, you have to decide which phrase is most important (viz., "John and Tom," "working together effectively," or "gathered in the basement"), and then place the phrase in the sentence accordingly.

Comment: This is another excellent permutation.

Answer (score 1):

> John and Tom, working together effectively, were gathered in the basement.

Personally, though correct, I think the other answers still sound unnatural. As a native speaker, I would say:

> John and Tom were gathered in the basement, working together effectively.

You could also say, with more stress on the effective work being done:

> John and Tom were working together effectively, gathered in the basement.

.

> Working together effectively were John and Tom, gathered in the basement.

.

> Effectively working together, John and Tom were gathered in the basement.

.

> John and Tom were working together effectively, gathered in the basement.

or stressing location similarly to the original:

> Gathered in the basement were John and Tom, working together effectively.

.

> Gathered in the basement, John and Tom were working together effectively.

All that said, "gathered" is a slightly unusual in this use referring to only two people. In any of the above examples, it can be removed without substitution. "together" is also unnecessary, as them being in the same place working effectively implies they are working together.

It's worth bearing in mind also, that all of these sentences have a very narrative, third-person storytelling sound to them - you wouldn't hear them in everyday speech.

If John and Tom are my friends who are building shelves in their basement, say, I would say:

> John and Tom were working productively in the basement (, and then x happened!)

Answer (score 0):

John and Tom gathered in the basement, and worked together effectively.

or, if you want to sound fancy,

Gathered in the basement, John and Tom worked effectively.

Comment: How does that sound "fancy"?